# Using An ArrayList To Access Specific Objects Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

How would I be able to access specific strings with and array list?

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.Add("Hi");
myList.Add("Pizza");
myList.Add("Can");
```

So if I did that and then I do:

```
for (String s : myList)
    if (s == "Hi")
        system.out.println("Hello"):
```

It would not print "Hello".

I need the size to change and see if the string exists but I can't seem to get this to work, any ideas?

Comment: You can't use `==` to test non-primitive objects for equality, generally. Override `Object.equals()` meaningfully and use it.

Comment: seems you are just using the loop for checking whether "Hi" is present or not. So for that `list.contains("Hi")` can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

**-** `Objects` in Java are compared using `equals()`, and `String` is **an Object in Java**, so it follows the same rule.

**-** `==` will be used to compare **primitive** or to check if **two or more Object Reference Variables are pointing to the same Object on the heap or not.**

**-** So you should use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` (if case doesn't matters) to compare the String Objects.

```
for (String s : myList){
    if (s.equals("Hi"))
        system.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (s == "Hi")
```

change it to

```
 if (s.equals("Hi"))
```

It is always better to use `equals()` while comparing objects than using `==` (except String literals)

`==` compares reference equality. `equals()` compares object content equality.

Answer (score 1):

You should write below code

```
for (String s : myList)
    if (s.equals("Hi"))
        system.out.println("Hello"):
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `s.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi")` if you do not care about upper-/lowercase

Comment: but s.equals("Hi") is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .equals() method it will check the value of the string while == checke Object reference.

Answer (score 1):

Method name is `add(object)` not `Add(). Here is an another answer

```
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("Hi");
        myList.add("Pizza");
        myList.add("Can");
        // method 1
        if( myList.contains("Hi")) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
        // method 2
        for( String word : myList ) {
            if( word.equals("Hi")) {
                System.out.println("found");
                // break the loop to avoid continues iteration
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **List.contains()**?

```
if (myList.contains("Hi"))
    system.out.println("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a HashMap? You can access the value by the get method of the HashMap.
You will avoid to make a loop on the ArrayList